# AG-Grid Angular - How Do You Disable loadingCellRenderer?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am simply trying to disable the loadingCellRenderer.

The URL to ag-grid page has code and example of it.  The "one moment" text line that appears in the row while it's initially loading... I am trying to just disable it off the bat.  Ag-Grid has a default fallback too of "Loading" if you don't use a custom one.  It seems like there would be a suppressLoadingCell.

I can hide the text with css, but that is not best.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-loading-cell-renderer/

Answer (score 1):

The grid property you probably are looking for is

```
gridOptions.suppressLoadingOverlay = true;
```

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-properties/#reference-overlays

Comment: that doesn't work.  It doesn't stop the row loading one.